# Checking that a certain function is equal to zero for all $|i-j|>1$

Tags: matrix, conditional

Suppose `s[i]` and `e[i]` are $m\times m$ matrices, where $i=1,\ldots, n$.

I would like to check for all $|i-j|>1$, `s[i].e[j]-e[j].s[i]` is equal to zero.

Is this the right code to check the above and then to print all of the cases? (I think the `Do[Print[..],{..}]` line needs to be fixed.)

```
For[j = 1, j <= n, j++,
For[i = 1, Abs[i - j] > 1, i++, f[i] = s[i].e[j] - e[j].s[i]]]
Do[Print[f[i]], {i, n}]
```

It would be great when printing all of the cases, the differences of the products of matrices are labelled as `f[i,j]`, to distinguish one from another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need for-loop:

As an example (n=5,m=3) create n mxm arrays:

```
s = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, m, m} ];
```

all different pairs:

```
pairs = Subsets[s, {2}];
```

matrixequation `f[i,j]`:

```
Map[#[[1]].#[[2]] - #[[2]].#[[1]] &, pairs]
```

That's it, hope it helps...

Answer (score 4):

Using `s` as defined by Ulrich,

```
Outer[AllTrue[Flatten[#1.#2 - #2.#1], EqualTo[0]] &, s, s, 1];
```

gives a matrix of booleans that checks if the commutators are zero element by element.  You might want to replace `EqualTo[0]` with `LessThan[0.0001]@*Abs` (or something) if you want to allow for some floating point jitter.  You can also try something like

```
Outer[Tr[#\[ConjugateTranspose].#] &@(#1.#2 - #2.#1) &, s, s, 1];
```

if you want to judge the commutator as a whole.  To examine the commutators of `s` with `e`, replace on of the `s` arguments of `Outer` with `e`.